# Adding a new crossref type for a user-defined environment

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, counters

In short, I'm trying to define an environment `comment` which has its own crossref type and counter. I want to be able to refer to these comment environments later.

Looks like `cleveref` does what I want, but I find the documentation a little hard to follow. From what I can make out, this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{CommentCount}
\setcounter{CommentCount}{1}
\crefalias{CommentCount}{comments}

\newenvironment{comment}[1][\theCommentCount]
    {\label[comments]{#1}\textbf{Comment \#\theCommentCount:}\itshape}
    {\stepcounter{CommentCount}}

\begin{document}

Some text

\begin{comment}[wibble]
more text
\end{comment}

See Comment~\cref{comments}{wibble}.

\end{document}
```

But this gives: `! Use of \cref@override@label@type doesn't match its definition.`

Am I close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `\crefalias`, I would use the instruction

```
\crefname{CommentCount}{comment}{comments}
```

Since you're going to use the counter for cross-referencing purposes, you should use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter` to increment the counter variable `CommentCount`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{CommentCount}
\setcounter{CommentCount}{0}

\newenvironment{comment}[1]
    {\refstepcounter{CommentCount}%
     \label{comment:#1}%
     \par\noindent\textbf{Comment \#\theCommentCount:}\itshape}
    {\par}

\usepackage{cleveref}  % load "cleveref" as late as possible
\crefname{CommentCount}{Comment}{Comments}

\begin{document}
Some text\dots
\begin{comment}{wibble}
More text
\end{comment}
\begin{comment}{wobble}
Still more text
\end{comment}
See \cref{comment:wibble,comment:wobble}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I wanted. Kudos!